# tmap, tm_arrange, make maps of similar size

Tags: r, tmap

I am currently producing maps using `R`’s package `tmap`.

My goal is to combine two maps in a single PDF, and I want the extent of each map to be the same.

The first map zooms in a given country and shows a polygon. The second map shows the country and the area the first map zooms in.

Unfortunately, I am not able to find a way to produce maps that are of similar size.

I have unsuccessfully tried to play with aspect ratio, but this did not go very far.

Does anyone know how to force the maps to be the same size when I use `tm_arrange`?

I guess I have to make proportional the `osm_extract` as this is the base for both maps. I am not sure how, though. I was thinking about using a ratio of the polygon size relative to the country size.

Below is my code and two output examples. One is in Belgium and the other in Chile.

```
# Load relevant libraries
library(dplyr)
library(sf)
library(rnaturalearth)
library(rnaturalearthdata)
library(tmaptools)
library(tmap)


# Load a polygon
pol <- st_read("~/Desktop/pol.shp")

# Describe pol
pol$geometry
# Geometry set for 1 feature 
# Geometry type: POLYGON
# Dimension:     XY
# Bounding box:  xmin: 4.672922 ymin: 50.54922 xmax: 4.998377 ymax: 50.8366
# Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84

# Get the world polygon and retain Belgium
Belgium <- ne_countries(scale = "medium", returnclass = "sf") %>%
  dplyr::filter(admin=="Belgium")

# Bounding Box of polygon
bbox_list <- lapply(st_geometry(pol), st_bbox)
maxmin <- as.data.frame(matrix(unlist(bbox_list),nrow=nrow(pol)))

# OSM extract -- This is what to make proportional?
osm_extract <- read_osm(bb(x=pol,cx=(maxmin$V1+maxmin$V3)/2,cy=(maxmin$V2+maxmin$V4)/2), ext=1.2) 

# Generate bounding box for second map
polys_list <- lapply(bbox_list, st_as_sfc)
bounding_box = polys_list[[1]]
st_crs(bounding_box) <- st_crs(pol)

# Map of the polygon
map = tm_shape(osm_extract) + tm_rgb() +
  tm_shape(pol) + tm_borders() + tm_polygons() + tmap_options(check.and.fix = TRUE) + 
  tm_compass() + tm_scale_bar() +
  tm_layout(frame = FALSE, 
            legend.outside = FALSE,
            legend.show = FALSE) 

tmap_save(map, "~/Desktop/map.pdf",width=6,height=4.5,unit="in")

### Make Map of the Country + Bounding Box
bbox_list <- lapply(st_geometry(Belgium), st_bbox)
maxmin <- as.data.frame(matrix(unlist(bbox_list),nrow=nrow(Belgium)))

# OSM extract -- This is what to make proportional?
osm_extract <- read_osm(bb(x=Belgium,cx=(maxmin$V1+maxmin$V3)/2,cy=(maxmin$V2+maxmin$V4)/2), ext=1.1) 

# Map of the country
ctry_map = tm_shape(osm_extract) + tm_rgb() +
  tm_shape(bounding_box) + tm_fill(col="#FFC300") + tmap_options(check.and.fix = TRUE) +
  tm_compass() + tm_scale_bar() +
  tm_layout(frame = FALSE, 
            legend.outside = FALSE,
            legend.show = FALSE) 


tmap_save(ctry_map, "~/Desktop/ctry_map.pdf",width=6,height=4.5,unit="in")


# Bind map
maps <- tmap_arrange(ctry_map,map,
                     ncol=2,
                     nrow=1,
                     widths=c(.5,.5),
                     heights=c(.5,.5)) 

tmap_save(maps, "~/Desktop/map_ctry_map.pdf",width=6,height=4.5,unit="in")
```

[image: Chile]
[Belgium](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mn16D.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I have found one solution.

I make the extracted osm proportional to the country's bounding box.

```
    ## Generate bounding box of the country
    bbox_list <- lapply(st_geometry(temp_worldmap), st_bbox)
    ctry_maxmin <- as.data.frame(matrix(unlist(bbox_list),nrow=nrow(temp_worldmap)))
    
    # Absolute width
    width = max(ctry_maxmin$V1,ctry_maxmin$V3)-min(ctry_maxmin$V1,ctry_maxmin$V3)
    # Absolute height
    height = max(ctry_maxmin$V2,ctry_maxmin$V4)-min(ctry_maxmin$V2,ctry_maxmin$V4)
    # Ratio height to width
    ratio_h_w=height/width
```

then:

```
    osm_extract <- read_osm(bb(x=pol,cx=(maxmin$V1+maxmin$V3)/2,cy=(maxmin$V2+maxmin$V4)/2, width=1, height=ratio_h_w))
```